# Support users with old version of Google Play Services installed

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I'm working on a small app, trying to support android 4 and higher. I also want to keep statistics about the user activity. My initial choice for this was Firebase, yet i see a major problem with event tracking through it: if user has an outdated Google Play Services installed on a device, i can't fire an event because of SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED error. This means i have no way of tracking users with outdated Google Services app, and i can't even count how many users I'm ignoring. Am i missing something? Is there a way around it? Why would firebase SDK need to rely on external dependency for a simple thing like event tracking?..

Thanks.